# Unable to find a specification for `FirebaseCoreOnly (~> 6.33.0)`

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-ios

In my flutter application am using Firebase push notifications. Am getting the below error.

```
Unable to find a specification for `FirebaseCoreOnly (~> 6.33.0)` depended upon by `firebase_messaging`

You have either:
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.
```

I have tried the following ways:

1. pod install
2. pod repo update
3. rm Podfile && flutter build ios

But nothing helps. I have also seen to use **pod repo remove master** but I am getting the below error:

```
[!] repo master does not exist
```

And when I run **pod repo list** am getting the below list

```
trunk
- Type: CDN
- URL:  https://cdn.cocoapods.org/
- Path: /Users/sivabala.d/.cocoapods/repos/trunk

1 repo
```

Any other suggestions or am doing it in the wrong way?

Comment: do you have firebase core in your dependencies/pubspec

Comment: Yes, in pub spec. firebase_core: ^0.5.0+1